# Jolt JSON Transformer

Tags: json, jolt

I want to transform the given json in to the given format using jolt:-

**Input JSON**

```
{
  "dataType": "XYZ",
  "payload": {
    "Revision": 0,
    "identifier2": {
      "xyz": 215,
      "version": 1,
      "revision": 1,
      "Type": 12
    },
    "timestamp": "2019-12-10T06:24:01.708Z",
    "Currency": "SEK",
    "identifier3": {
      "xyz": 170,
      "version": 1,
      "revision": 5,
      "Type": 40
    }
  },
  "datatype1": "ABC"
}

**Output JSON:-**

   {
  "dataType": "XYZ",
  "payload": {
    "Revision": 0,
    "identifier2": {
      "xyz": 215,
      "version": 1,
      "revision": 1,
      "Type": 12
    },
    "timestamp": "2019-12-10T06:24:01.708Z",
    "Currency": {
      "Value": "SEK",
      "Domain": null
    },
    "identifier3": {
      "xyz": 170,
      "version": 1,
      "revision": 5,
      "Type": 40
    }
  },
  "datatype1": "ABC"
}
```

**My SPEC:-**

```
      [
        {
          "operation": "shift",
          "spec": {
            "payload": {
              "Currency": {
                "*": {
                  "$": "&2.Value",
                  "@": "&2.Domain"
                }
              },
              "*": "payload.&"
            },
            "*": ".&"
          }
      }
]
```

While i am using this spec its moving the Currency Tag out of the payload. Please tell me how to do it correctly. I am able to split the currency using this spec but its moving out of the payload tag.

Answer (score 0):

Your mapping rule of *&2.Value* placed *&2* (Currency) at top level, if you change that mapping rule to *payload.&2.Value* or *&3.&2.Value* it will place it under *payload* as expected.

I tested all the JOLT specs using the [jolt-demo website](https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/)

### Quick fix

With literal *payload*:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "payload": {
        "Currency": {
          "*": {
            "$": "payload.&2.Value",
            "@": "payload.&2.Domain"
          }
        },
        "*": "payload.&"
      },
      "*": "&"
    }
  }
]
```

With wildcard *&3* (3 levels up from current position):

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "payload": {
        "Currency": {
          "*": {
            "$": "&3.&2.Value",
            "@": "&3.&2.Domain"
          }
        },
        "*": "payload.&"
      },
      "*": "&"
    }
  }
]
```

### Taking a wild JOLT

Just in case your expected input documents are in the same form of the example JSON you provided:

```
{
  ...
  "payload": {
    ...
    "Currency": "value"
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

And you are not expecting *payload.Currency* to be in the form of:

```
...
"Currency": {
  "key": "value",
  "key1": "value1",
  ...
}
...
```

And your end goal is to map the value of *payload.Currency* to *payload.Currency.Value* and add a default value of *null* to *payload.Currency.Value* (in case it's empty), *payload.Currency.Domain* (per your example output)

Then you may consider a more direct / simpler SPEC:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "payload": {
        "Currency": "&1.&.Value",
        "*": "&1.&"
      },
      "*": "&"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "payload": {
        "Currency": {
          "Value": null,
          "Domain": null
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```